# Rails: Losing flash/errors from embedded form after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, has-many, partials

This is a stupid example but I'm trying to understand how thing get passed around behind the scenes in Rails. And there's probably a better, "Rails", way to approach this...if so please let me know. I have:

```
Warren has_many Rabbits
Rabbit belongs_to Warren
```

I'm listing existing rabbits and then providing a form for adding a new rabbit.

**warrens/show.html.haml**

```
%h1 This Warren

%h2 Rabbits
= render @warren.rabbits, :target => @warren

%h2 Add a rabbit:
= render "rabbits/form", :parent => @warren, :foreign_key => :warren_id

= link_to 'Edit', edit_warren_path(@warren)
\|
= link_to 'Back', warrens_path
```

It works. I can add and destroy rabbits while looking at the Warren's show view. The problem is that the **flash** messages (`:success`, `:notice`) and/or the `rabbit.errors` aren't being shown on/in the view. Now, I am **not** using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my warren.rb model. but this is *mostly* working. Learning Rails so wondering what's going on and **how to get my messages flowing smoothly**...

**rabbits/_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for ([parent, parent.rabbits.build]) do |f| 
    = render "shared/error_messages", :target => parent

    .field
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name
    .field
        = f.label :color
        = f.text_field :color
    .field
        = f.hidden_field foreign_key
    .actions
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

**layouts/application.html.haml**

```
    !!!
    %html
        %head
               ...
        %body
            .container
                - flash.each do |key, value|
                    %div{ :class => ['flash', key] }= value
                = yield
```

**rabbits_controller.rb**

```
class RabbitsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @warren = Warren.find(params[:warren_id])
    @rabbit = @warren.rabbits.create(params[:rabbit])
    redirect_to @warren
  end

  def destroy
    @warren = Warren.find(params[:warren_id])
    @rabbit = @warren.rabbits.find(params[:id])
    @rabbit.destroy
    redirect_to @warren
  end
```

**shared/_error_messages.html.haml**

```
-if target.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2= "#{pluralize(target.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this record from being saved:"
    %ul
      - target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

Comment: I don't see where you are setting flash messages...  Should be in rabbits_controller.rb.

Comment: yup! got that now. thanks! still struggling with the **error messages**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are not setting the flash messages in your controller.  Try the following:

```
def create
  @warren = Warren.find(params[:warren_id])
  @rabbit = @warren.rabbits.create(params[:rabbit])
  redirect_to @warren, :flash => { :info => "Rabbit was just born." }
end

def destroy
  @warren = Warren.find(params[:warren_id])
  @rabbit = @warren.rabbits.find(params[:id])
  @rabbit.destroy
  redirect_to @warren, :flash => { :info => "Rabbit was brutally murdered!" }
end
```

Alternatively, I believe you can use `:success` / `notice`:

```
redirect_to @warren, :success => "Rabbit was brutally murdered!"
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

For your error messages, you need something like `target.error_messages`.  You can find more details on customizing the output [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view).

Comment: thanks! it does! learning and with so much going on I, plainly, forgot to specify the :flash. Thanks! Now any idea **how to capture & display the error messages (.errors)?**  Problem clearly with temporary @vendor.items.build object being used to build the form...but when rabbits_controller's create method fails validation I can't figure out how to get ahold of the errors?!?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3 and get "undefined method" for `error_messages` and deprecation warnings for `error_messages_for`!?! Not sure why they're still in the Rails 3 docs? Says you need to install a plugin to get them back. Unless I'm using them incorrectly I'm wondering what the "Rails 3 way" (ha!) is?

Comment: Hmm...  Maybe try replacing `render "shared/error_messages", :target => parent` with `render "shared/error_messages", :locals => { :target => parent }`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I think what's happening is that `parent` (from `_form.html.haml`'s perspective) is a `@warren`. But, what this *partial* is accepting arguments for and *should* be reporting errors on is an instance of `Rabbit`. Problem, the way **I** see it, is I'm "building" the Rabbit instance to render the form with `parent.rabbits.build` and for reasons **beyond my knowledge** those errors aren't getting passed back when `rabbits_controller.rb` has a validation error and imposes a `redirect_to`. **Perhaps I should be passing a Rabbit in as `:target`?** But how?

Comment: In each partial - try adding some debugging to see exactly what is going on.  In ERB it would be `<%= debug @object %>`.

Comment: Well, that helped! And got me looking down what was ultimately the path to the answer. I was calling `redirect_to` when I should have been calling `render` after the failed errors. Learned a bit about difference between `render` & `redirect_to` in the process. Anyway, it's finally working as I had hoped now.. with a little refactoring it might actually even *look* elegant. Thanks for all your help!